# CSS :selector doesn't work with different tags?

Tags: css, tags, selector

Say I have

```
<div class="myClass">
   <div class="child"></div>
   <span class="child"></span>
   <a class="child"></a>
</div>
```

If I use

```
.child:first-of-type { /* Code here */ }
```

Then all three tags get the CSS code since they are all of different types. Is there a way of still using this selector but with different tags?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HrSwT/)

first-of-type selects as its type but you have defined every child with different types. In the demo I have provided there are two more div (of-type) added in which first div is being selected and another (of-type) is span which is only one so it is selecting if you add more span then it doesn't select other span.

In your case, if you want to select only first then apply `:first-child`

> The :first-of-type CSS pseudo-class represents the first sibling of its type in the list of children of its parent element. [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type)

**Example taken from MDN provide the source above**

```
div :first-of-type {
  /*background-color: lime;*/
  font-weight: bold;
}


<div>
  <span>This span is first!</span>
  <span>This span is not. :(</span>
  <span>what about this <em>nested element</em>?</span>
  <strike>This is another type</strike>
  <span>Sadly, this one is not...</span>
</div>
```

Result:

**This span is first!** This span is not. :( what about this **nested element**? **This is another type** Sadly, this one is not...

Answer (score 3):

Just add the tag to the selector, e.g.

```
div.child:first-of-type { /* Code here */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

[From docs:](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/%3afirst-of-type)

**Pseudo-class `:first-of-type`**

*The `:first-of-type` pseudo-class represents an element that is the first sibling of its type in the list of children of its parent element. Same as `:nth-of-type(1)`.*

**Syntax**

```
selector:first-of-type{ properties }
```